# What is the symbol for all folders in a folder when you dir a path and export to .txt?

Tags: batch, cmd.exe

I have a folder called `root\sound\weapons`. In `root\sound\weapons` I have: `ak`, `m4`, `m9`, etc., and in each of these, I have five sounds.

I want to `dir` `root\sound\weapons\ak,m4,m9\*dist.wav /B /O >Paths.txt` without writing down the name of each weapon. I will batch this. Batch is in the Mods folder before `root\sound\weapons`.

How can I dir `root\sound\weapons\*.*\*dist.wav /B /O >Paths.txt`?

Comment: You are more likely to get some help if you start upvoting and [accepting answers](http://superuser.com/help/accepted-answer) to your other questions where people (for free in their spare time) have helped you. This shows your appreciation of their efforts and also shows the answers are useful.

Comment: Please also read [Why is voting important?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote)